# Isometry between c and C(X)

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry

Let $c=\left\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \in  \ell^\infty: \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\mbox{ exists}\right\}$ and $X = \{1/n : n \in \Bbb {N} \} \cup \{0\}$.

Define $T:c \to C(X)$ by $T((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}) = f$, where $f(1/n)= x_n$ and $f(0)$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$.

How can I show that $T$ is an isometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $y=(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be elements of $c$.
We need to show that $\|T(x)-T(y)\|_{_{C(X)}}=\|x-y\|_{c}$.
We have that

$$
\|T(x)-T(y)\|_{_{C(X)}} = \sup_{u\in X} |f(u)-g(u)|,
$$

where $f(1/n)=x_n$ and $f(0)= \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, and, $g(1/n)=y_n$ and $g(0)= \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n$.
Therefore,

\begin{align}
\|T(x)-T(y)\|_{_{C(X)}}& = \max\{|f(0)-g(0)|, \sup_{n\in \mathbb N} |f(1/n)-g(1/n)|\}\\ &
= \max\{|f(0)-g(0)|, \sup_{n\in \mathbb N} |x_n-y_n|\}\\&
= \max\{|f(0)-g(0)|, \|x-y\|_{c}\}.
\end{align}

Moreover, note that

\begin{align}
|f(0)-g(0)|&=\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n - \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n\right| = |\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n - y_n|
=\lim_{n\to \infty} |x_n-y_n|,
\end{align}
and since $|x_n-y_n|\leq \|x-y\|_c$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, it follows that
$$
|f(0)-g(0)|\leq \|x-y\|_c.
$$
So, according to the previous equation, we have that
$$
\|T(x)-T(y)\|_{_{C(X)}} = \max\{|f(0)-g(0)|, \|x-y\|_{c}\} = \|x-y\|_{c}.
$$

Comment: That's very clear, thanks! The only bit I'm not sure about was why we want to find the max between |f(0)-g(0)| and sup|f(1/n)-g(1/n)|   ? I wondered if we ought to take it in two separate cases, one where it is 0, the other when it is 1/n ?

Comment: We take the max between $|f(0)-g(0)|$ and $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|f(1/n)-g(1/n)|$ because we are taking the sup at all points of $X$, and this includes $0$.

Answer (score 1):

First show it is linear: for $x,y \in c$ and $a \in \mathbb{F}$,
$T(ax+y)=f$, where $f(1/n)=ax_n+y_n$. Now, $T(x)=f_1$ where $f_1(1/n)=x_n$ and $T(y)=f_2$ where $f(1/n)=y_n$, so in total,
$$T(ax+y)=f=af_1+f_2=aT(x)+T(y).$$

Next, show it preserves norm:

If $x\in c$, $\|x\|= \sup_n |x_n|=\sup_n |f(1/n)|=\|f\|=\|Tx\|$.

Comment: Is it so straightforward that $\|f\|=\sup_nf(1/n)$?

Comment: I definitely missed some absolute values there.  I suppose that they are continuous at $0$ is required, but that's just the definition of $C(X)$.